# Why is ```(n+1)(BASE-1)``` added when calculating the NMAX of Adler-32?

Tags: zlib, adler32

[zlib/adler32.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/adler32.c)
code is:

```c
#define BASE 65521U     /* largest prime smaller than 65536 */
#define NMAX 5552
/* NMAX is the largest n such that 255n(n+1)/2 + (n+1)(BASE-1) <= 2^32-1 */
```

but I think it should be calculated like this:

```c
255n(n+1)/2 + n < 2^32 - 1
```

What is the purpose of adding `(n+1)(BASE-1)`?

Comment: Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Think about the assumptions behind your calculation.

Comment: My understanding is that the cumulative sum cannot exceed the value range of the integer type (integer overflow).

Comment: True. What else did you assume?

Comment: 1. Assume that each input byte is the maximum value (255): input = [255, 255, 255...]

2. Assume that adler and sum2 are the maximum values: adler = 65520; sum2 = 65520

Comment: Those _are_ the right assumptions, but somehow you got the math wrong! I thought for sure you were making the common mistake of assuming initial values of 1 and 0 instead of 65520 and 65520, because if you incorrectly assume 1 and 0, you get _exactly_ your "should be calculated like this". I don't know how you got the math wrong with the correct assumptions.